# How to stop WNetAddConnection2 to connect on port 80 of destination host?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a requirement where my software should store the smb server settings including IP\sharedFolder, username, password, and mapping it to particular drive.

I am using WNetAddConnection2 API which is successful if all parameters are correct. It connects to port 445 (SMB/SMB2) and does the authentication.

If I pass username/password wrong, it tries to authenticate first on port 445 and once its failed it tries http authentication on port 80 using webdav. I dont want it to connect to port 80 as firewall is raising an alert on the destination host.

Is there any way I can disable communication on port 80 using WNetAddConnection2 ? Or other way to map the drive?